# Tabnet on GCP Vertex Workbench Error: No module named 'google_cloud_pipeline_components.experimental'

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to run the tabnet model on GCP Vertex workbench. Right now, I am just trying to run the example model, located here (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/tabular_workflows/tabnet_on_vertex_pipelines.ipynb). When I get to the Import libraries and define constants section, I keep running into the following issue.

```
import os
import uuid
from typing import Any, Dict, List

from google.cloud import aiplatform, storage
from google_cloud_pipeline_components.experimental.automl.tabular import \
    utils as automl_tabular_utils
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named google_cloud_pipeline_components.experimental`
```

I have copied the code exactly as written in the sample workbook. The only thing I have added in is my project info, bucket, and service account.

I have tried the following:

- Rerun the project multiple times.
- Deleted the notebook and rebuilt it
- Removed the --upgrade addition from the original install
- Removed the .experimental.automl.tabular portion of the command
  This did remove the error, but caused an error later on in the workbook
- Removed the package install and reinstalled